# Pagination on click, the number of the url changes but the next page dont load react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, pagination, fetch-api

My pagination is working if I change the URL manually example /diet/1, 2 or 3. I've implemented a function to add page + 1 and `onClick` the numbers are changing on the URL but the page is not loading the next content? My code below: Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
const Survey = props => {

const history = useHistory()
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({})
const { count, setCount, percentage, setPercentage } = useContext(AppContext)
const pageId = parseInt(props.pageId)
const [page, setPage] = useState(pageId)
const [results, setResults] = useState([])
const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(5)

useEffect(() => {
    surveyApi()
    return () => {}
}, [])

const surveyApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/surveyoptions?page=${page}`)
    const results = await response.json()
    setResults(results.result)
    setPage(page)
    setTotalPages(page)
}

const getPageLink = ( pageNo ) => {
    return `/diet/${ pageNo }`
}


return (
    <>

 <Link 
    to={getPageLink(page + 1)}
    onClick={ () => setPage(page + 1) }
    className="next">
    Click Link 
 </Link> 
      </>
    )
  }

  export default Survey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const Survey = props => {

const history = useHistory()
const [selected, setSelected] = useState({})
const { count, setCount, percentage, setPercentage } = useContext(AppContext)
const pageId = parseInt(props.pageId)
const [page, setPage] = useState(pageId)
const [results, setResults] = useState([])
const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(5)

useEffect(() => {
    surveyApi()
}, [page]) // <--- pass `page` here.

const surveyApi = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/surveyoptions?page=${page}`)
    const results = await response.json()
    setResults(results.result)
    setPage(page)
    setTotalPages(page)
}

const getPageLink = ( pageNo ) => {
    return `/diet/${ pageNo }`
}


return (
    <>

 <Link 
    to={getPageLink(page + 1)}
    onClick={ () => setPage(page + 1) }
    className="next">
    Click Link 
 </Link> 
      </>
    )
  }

  export default Survey
```

Comment: Brooo thanks, It took me ages to figure out! That I decided to get extra help haha Thank you so much!!